# upload form validation callback not running on ajax codeigniter hmvc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have this upload form,

here is the view

```
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userfile" class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2">File<span>*</span></label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="userfile" name="userfile" >
          </div>
      </div>
          <div class="form-group has-error col-sm-offset-7">
            <label class="form-group has-error control-label" for="error"><?php echo form_error("userfile"); ?></label>
          </div>
    </div>
*other input type='text' divs
```

and here is the controller

```
public function do_upload(){

    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/pdf';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size']    = 0;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile',   'Document'         ,'callback_handle_upload');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_NAME',   'Document Name'    ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_TYPE',   'Document Type'    ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_DATE',   'Date'             ,'trim|required');

    $file_data = $this->upload->data();
    $url = base_url().'uploads/pdf/'.$file_data['file_name'];

    if($this->form_validation->run($this)){

          if($this->upload->do_upload()){//upload function

            $this->PDFuploads_Model->insert($url);
          }

    }else{

      $this->add_view();
    }
}
```

and the call back is

```
  public function handle_upload()
  {
    if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
      {
      if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
      {
        // set a $_POST value for 'userfile' that we can use later
        $upload_data    = $this->upload->data();
        $_POST['userfile'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        // possibly do some clean up ... then throw an error
        $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
        return false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // throw an error because nothing was uploaded
      $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', "You must upload a document!");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**ALL OF THIS WORKS PERFECTLY FINE**.
now, i have a ajax function for form validation. But **when i put ajax validation** on this **ALL form validation WORKS and shows error except for form validation for upload**.. so i assume form validation or callback methods are the problem, i have already put this `MY_Form_validation` library on my libraries.

here is what the controller looks like when i put it on ajax validation

```
public function do_upload(){

    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/pdf';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size']    = 0;


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile',   'Document'         ,'callback_handle_upload');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_NAME',   'Document Name'    ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_TYPE',   'Document Type'    ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_DATE',   'Date'             ,'trim|required');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"','</p>');

    $file_data = $this->upload->data();
    $url = base_url().'uploads/pdf/'.$file_data['file_name'];

    if($this->form_validation->run($this)){

          if($this->upload->do_upload()){//upload function

            $this->PDFuploads_Model->insert($url);
          }

          $data['success'] = true;
    }else{

      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        # code...
        $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);

      }

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and also here is the ajax

```
$('#form-user').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this);

    // perform ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: me.attr('action'),
        type: 'post',
        data: me.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success == true) {
                // if success we would show message
                // and also remove the error class
                $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
                    ' Data has been saved' +
                    '</div>');
                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                                .removeClass('has-success');
                $('.text-danger').remove();

                // reset the form
                me[0].reset();

                // close the message after seconds
                $('.alert-success').delay(200).show(10, function() {
                    $(this).delay(200).hide(10, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                })
            }
            else {
                $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                    var element = $('#' + key);

                    element.closest('div.form-group')
                    .removeClass('has-error')
                    .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : '')
                    .find('.text-danger')
                    .remove();

                    element.after(value);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

why is it that **only** the form validation for upload file does not show if its on ajax

Comment: Not sure yet, but you have the same name and the same ID (what is wrong!) for label and input file field. Change it

Comment: @mamosek i already changed it but i dont think it is the problem.

Comment: You have no errors only for file upload? Maybe try to debug if $_FILES['userfile'] is not empty and you send data to it in your handle_upload() , debug some informations.

Comment: it just dont show the error when it is on ajax. else, its fine.